# How to import a .py file on jupyter notebook using the directory

Tags: python, directory, jupyter-notebook, sys

I want to import .py file on jupyter notebook using a directory. How can i import this file on jupyter.
file path - C:\Users\Documents\AFR\hunk.py

For eg i want to import all the functions from the test_standard.py file in to my main.py
Like this

```
import sys 
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("/Users/hp/Documents/AFR"))
import test_standard.py
```

But I am receiving the error
No module named 'test_standard.py'; 'test_standard' is not a package

@james

Answer (score 0):

Instead of
import test_standard.py #incorrect
import test_standard #will work as filename needs to be imported